# Plotting a function that is not defined for all values with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am plotting functions like these:

```
eq <-function(x) ifelse(x<(-1)|x>1|(x>(-1)& x<1),(x/((x^2)-1)),NA)
eq2 <-function(x) ifelse(x<(-sqrt(2))|x>sqrt(2)|x>(-sqrt(2))&x<sqrt(2),(x/((x^2)-2)), NA)
eq3 <-function(x) ifelse(x<(-sqrt(3))|x>sqrt(3)|x>(-sqrt(3))&x<sqrt(3),(x/((x^2)-3)), NA)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-3,3)), aes(x))+
  stat_function(fun=eq,geom="line", aes(colour="x/(x^2-1)"))+
  stat_function(fun=eq2,geom='line',aes(color='x/(x^2-2)')) +
  stat_function(fun=eq3,geom='line', aes(color ='x/(x^2-3)'))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = (seq(-3, 3, by = 0.5)))+ ylim(-3,3)
```

This creates a plot but the lines seem to stop randomly. I would like them to continue to the edge of the plot. I am fairly certain my code is equivalent to the answer to this question [Plotting Noncontinuous Function ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183063/plotting-noncontinuous-function-ggplot2). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: For single point discontinuities, I think you code would be much cleaner if you just checked for equality at the points, e.g., `ifelse(x == -1 | x == 1, NA, x / (x^2 - 1))`. I'm also a bit skeptical of how appropriate `stat_function` is for highlighting pointwise discontinuities - the discontinuities won't show up unless the exact values `-1` and `1` are passed in.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor that is much cleaner! Any suggestions for alternatives to stat_function?

Comment: No - I retract that point. I was thinking of a different sort of function/discontinuity.

Comment: Alright. I did implement the suggested changes though! =)

Comment: Another option would be `ifelse(x %in% c(-1, 1), NA, x / (x^2 - 1))`, which can be easier than lots of `| ==`.

Comment: True! I always forget about that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ylim(-3,3)` is causing data values outside that range to be removed from the plot (which also happens with `scale_y_continuous`). Use `coord_cartesian` to set limits without removing data outside those limits:

```
  ylim(-10,10) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3))
```

In the code above, I've also set a `ylim` range, but one much larger than the range limits for the graph. This is to avoid vertical lines where the function values blow up to `Inf` or `-Inf`.

Comment: This is great. I've also set `coord_cartesion(xlim=(-3,3))` and set x to -5,5 ;)